# Skip select option if default value come

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Im working into full calendar `add_event`  and I have something like his:

```
$('#event_add').unbind('click').click(function () {
    var title =
       $('#lstProveedor option:selected').html() +
        ' - ' +
        $('#lstcuadrilla option:selected').html() +
        ' - ' +
        $('#lstSucursal option:selected').html() +
        ' - ' +
        $('#lstRegion option:selected').html() +
        ' - ' +
        $('#lstSolicitud option:selected').html();
    addEvent(title);
});
```

For example: if selected value of `$('#lstProveedor option:selected').html() +' - '`  is `"select an option"` don´t count it, just skip can I do that? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking the index, if its 0 then its default value in your case.

```
$('#event_add').unbind('click').click(function () {
  var title = "";
  if($('#lstProveedor').prop('selectedIndex') !== 0){
    title += $('#lstProveedor option:selected').html() + "-";
  }
   if($('#lstcuadrilla').prop('selectedIndex') !== 0){
    title += $('#lstcuadrilla option:selected').html() + "-";
  }
   if($('#lstSucursal').prop('selectedIndex') !== 0){
    title += $('#lstSucursal option:selected').html() + "-";
  }
  if($('#lstRegion').prop('selectedIndex') !== 0){
    title += $('#lstRegion option:selected').html() + "-";
  }
  if($('#lstSolicitud').prop('selectedIndex') !== 0){
    title += $('#lstSolicitud option:selected').html() + "-";
  }
  title= title.slice(0,-1);
  addEvent(title);
});
```

Or you can simply add one common class to every select you need to consider for concatenation and then can use code like following!

```
$('#event_add').off('click').click(function () {
  var title = "";
  $(".commonclass").each(function(i,e){
      if($(this).prop('selectedIndex') !== 0){
        title += $(this).find("option:selected").text() + "-";
      }
  });
  title= title.slice(0,-1);
  addEvent(title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
var title = '';
if($('#lstProveedor option:selected').val() == "select an option") {
    var proveedor = '';
} else {
    var proveedor = $('#lstProveedor option:selected').html() + ' - ')
}
title = proveedor + cuadrilla + sucursal + solicitud;
```

And separate the other options into variables to concatenate the same way..